# jQuery background image slideshow not showing images in browser bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm having an issue with my jQuery background slideshow images, the images work perfectly when i open my project in the live view for both of my code editors(namely Visual Studio Code and Brackets) but when I open the project through the folder and index.html the images don't display but the linear gradient i applied to the images is present, this is the case in both Chrome and Internet Explorer.

The jQuery was coded in an earlier version - I have the latest version in the project - this might cause a problem? - also this is my first project where I'm using Bootstrap 4, not sure if there is a problem with that but as I said above the slideshow works perfectly when viewed with my code editors

[image shows in live view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03tHj.jpg)

[image missing in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65c4C.jpg)

jQuery here.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Array of images which you want to show.
  var images = new Array(
    "../img/head-anenomeRight.jpeg",
    "../img/head-clownAnenome.jpeg",
    "../img/head-corals.jpeg",
    "../img/head-discus.jpg",
    "../img/head-yellowTang.jpg"
  );
  var nextimage = 0;
  doSlideshow();

  function doSlideshow() {
    if (nextimage >= images.length) {
      nextimage = 0;
    }
    $("#home")
      .css(
        "background-image",
        'linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)),url("' +
          images[nextimage++] +
          '")'
      )
      .fadeIn(500, function() {
        setTimeout(doSlideshow, 6000);
      });
  }
});
```

html here.

```
<!--Header-->
  <header id="home">
    <div class="home-inner container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8">
          <h1 class="display-3">Aquatics
            <span id="head-number-color">4 </span>Finatics</h1>
          <h3 class="display-5 mb-3">Professional Aquarium Solutions</h3>
          <a href="#expertise-section" id="learn-more" class="btn text-white">Learn More</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
```

css here.

```
#home {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  min-height: 700px;
}
```

If anyone has a more efficient way of doing a background slideshow with Bootstrap or jQuery then I would be happy to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is correct. 
The problem should be the URL of images. Check if the path is ok.

Or try to save the images in other format, like png. Can be any pattern color problem.

Change your images like this and test if works:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //Array of images which you want to show.
        var images = new Array(
"https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/ed3/a-stormy-paradise-1-1563744.jpg",
"https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/f2c/effi-1-1366221.jpg",
"https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/851/poppies-1369329.jpg");
       var nextimage = 0;
       doSlideshow();

       function doSlideshow() {
          if (nextimage >= images.length) {
             nextimage = 0;
          }
          $("#home").css(
              "background-image",
              'linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)),url("' + images[nextimage++] + '")'
           ).fadeIn(500, function() {
              setTimeout(doSlideshow, 6000);
             });
          }
    });
```